# Context menu similar to the new Play Music application (v5.0.0)

Tags: android, design-patterns

You might have noticed in the new Play Music application (from version 5.0.0 onwards) the three dots close to every song, popping up a context menu:

[image: Play Music app with context menu open in one song]

I prefer the looks of these points when compared to the old triangle, similar to a spinner. I know this shouldn't be that difficult to implement from scratch, my question is:

Is there any new standard way of implementing this pattern (much alike the new Navigation Drawer pattern on the top-left side)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For a showing a popup list from a menu resource, use [PopupMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html), (or [PopupMenuCompat](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/PopupMenuCompat.html) for API below 11).

For a more complex list where you specify the adapter yourself, use [ListPopupWindow](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListPopupWindow.html) (or [ListPopupWindowCompat](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/ListPopupWindowCompat.html) API below 11).

Comment: Sounds that this is it! Will give it a try and mark this as accepted as soon as I do so. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

That is the [ListPopupMenu](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListPopupWindow.html) basically all you have to do is create an imageview with that drawable and call the `ListPopupMenu` on the image click

Answer (score 0):

It's just a custom spinner with the 3 dots image in the getView function and the options in the getDropdownView for the custom spinner adapter

Comment: I figured that could be implemented in a similar fashion, I just wanted to know if there was now a more standard way to do so :)

Comment: Nope. Since it's a fairly simple enough implementation i doubt there will ever be a new control or standard implementation for it. This actually is not a new control, it has been used before in Google Now and Google Play Store as well.

Comment: Now that I think of it, you're right, it was already present before! I guess I haven't thought a lot about it until I saw the Play Music app today :)